# Difference between resistor in conventional flow vs resistor in electron flow?

Tags: led, resistors

I understand the differences between conventional and electron flow. What I don't get resistors in conventional flow. Take this schematic as an example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFzawp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using conventional flow, one would expect the current to flow through the resistor, into the LED, and back into the battery. What doesn't make sense to me is how the LED doesn't burn out. Yes, there is a resistor, but if we use electron flow - the current flows into the LED first; not the resistor. How does the LED not burn out?

Comment: Electrons do _not_ flow, _current_ does. Electrons bounce around in a cloud inside and outside your circuit. If you want to learn electronics, forget everything about electrons. Learn about voltage and current.

Comment: @pipe but isn't current measured in amps? An an amp is a bunch of electrons flowing past a point in a specific period of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this circuit for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmD7jT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is functionally **identical** to your circuit, and yet by your reasoning it would have a completely different behaviour. So what gives?

Well, there is something you need to keep in mind:

> The current flowing through any point a series circuit is the same as every other.

When current flows through a resistor, a voltage drop occurs - see Ohms law. With the resistor in place, the current is limited which means the current through the LED must also limited, thus preventing any damage.

I think where you are getting confused is that you are thinking all of the current first flows through the LED as if the resistor were not there, and then flows through the resistor. This is not the case. The current flow will start **simultaneously** through both components (and also all of the wires) because it is being driven by the electrical potential generated by the voltage source which is across the whole circuit.

---

The only difference between conventional and electron current is a minus sign. There are no behavioural differences, the only reason for it is because a certain someone many years ago didn't know the full story and now we are stuck with it.

Comment: Agreed. Conventional current flow from + to - was decided on well before the discovery of the electron.